# How to display a model decoration in the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, decorator

I have build a searchmodel with a searchstring and decorated it with minlength. In my View I would like to display the requierements for the search string but how can I get to the decoration?

Model:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    [StringLength(50,MinimumLength = 4)]
    public string Searchname { get; set; }
}
```

Razor:

```
@model Project.Models.SearchModel

<p>
    The search value has to be a min length of: ... 
</p>
```

Comment: Constants? But I agree a function that gets the attribute values would be nicer. I think it's possible by using reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
@(typeof(SearchModel).GetProperty("Searchname").GetCustomAttributes(true)
    .OfType<StringLengthAttribute>().First().MinimumLength)
```

Though for the sake of MVC purity, you should probably avoid putting this logic into the view code. Either:

- Make your Controller get this information and put it onto the Model itself as a separate property, or
- Use a custom ModelMetadataProvider to make the information available via the model metadata.

Comment: I like your simple solution :-), but there is a problem **"No overload for method 'GetCustomAttributes' takes 0 arguments"** (Maybe need to add namespaces also?)

Comment: This work well: `typeof(NAMESPACE.SearchModel).GetProperty("Searchname").GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute>().First().MinimumLength`

Answer (score 1):

You can get this value from validator attribute in client side.

```
$('#Searchname').attr('data-val-length-min')
```

Or you need this in server side in razor?

```
@{
    var attr = typeof(NAMESPACE.SearchModel).GetProperty("Searchname").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute), true)[0];
    var min = attr.GetType().GetProperty("MinimumLength").GetValue(attr, null);
}
.
.
.
<p>The search value has to be a min length of: @min</p>
```

Comment: I have also thought about that and i will do it if there is no better way :-)

Comment: Added a razor/C# solution too. Enjoy!